# Uncaught TypeError: action.products.reduce is not a function

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-redux

So I took and example React-Redux repo from git the other day. I have been adding to it as practice to learn.  I am trying to rewrite the server-side code now so I can understand it better and eventually bring in a Mongo Database into the fold as well.  I have the server side code up and running and working but some of the existing code doesn't seem to work any more.  I am having trouble figuring out as to why.  The error I am getting is

Uncaught TypeError: action.products.reduce is not a function

Here is the code below.  I am not sure if it doesn't like the spread operator or  a general syntax thing which I have to make sure webpack handles correctly on the bundle.  Thanks in advance for any help!

```
function byId(state = {}, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case RECEIVE_PRODUCTS:
      return {
        ...state,
        ...action.products.reduce((obj, product) => {
          obj[product.id] = product
          return obj
        }, {})
      }
    default:
      const { productId } = action
      if (productId) {
        return {
          ...state,
          [productId]: products(state[productId], action)
        }
      }
      return state
  }
}
```

Below is the actions that get called before the reducer as requested.

```
function receiveProducts(products) {
  return {
    type: types.RECEIVE_PRODUCTS,
    products: products
  }
}

export function getAllProducts() {
  return dispatch => {
    shop.getProducts(products => {
      dispatch(receiveProducts(products))
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: its looking for the function action.products.map to be defined. I dont see it in the code you have above you may also be missing a dependency more info is needed

Comment: I guess it would make sense that the browser doesn't know the standard reduce or map functions in JS. It must have been handled differently in the server-side code that came with it.

Comment: Can you add the action which calls this reducer?

Comment: After doing some research there might be a limitation with babel-loader to handle the reduce/map functions.